# How to find elements that do not include a certain class name with selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I want to find all the elements that contain a certain class name but skip the ones the also contain another class name beside the one that i am searching for

I have the element `<div class="examplenameA">` and the element `<div class="examplenameA examplenameB">`

At the moment i am doing this to overcome my problem:

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('examplenameA')
for item in items:
    cname = item.get_attribute('class')
    if 'examplenameB' in cname:
        pass
    else:
        rest of code
```

I only want the elements that have the class name `examplenameA` and i want to skip the ones that also contain `examplenameB`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find all the elements with **class** *attribute* as **`examplenameA`** leaving out the ones with **class** *attribute* as **`examplenameB`** you can use the following solution:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.examplenameA:not(.examplenameB)")
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  items = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'examplenameA') and not(@class='examplenameB')]")
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use xpath in this case. So as per your example you need to use something like `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class='examplenameA')`. This will give you only the elements whose class is `examplenameA`

So how xpath works is : `Xpath=//tagname[@attribute='value']`

Hence the class is considered as the attribute & xpath will try to match the exact given value, in this case `examplenameA`, so `<div class="examplenameA examplenameB">` will be ignored

In case of `find_elements_by_class_name method`, it will try to match the element which has the class as `examplenameA`, so the `<div class="examplenameA examplenameB">` will also be matched

Hope this helps