# How to find element by div class excluding all with td class

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, calendar, css-selectors

I'm using Xpath and trying to find all td's with a div class name of 'day' excluding those with a td class name of 'invalid_day'.

This is for a calendar using selenium Xpath to select only the matching div class 'day' in the selected month.  Ignoring any div class 'day' from the previous or future month.

**HTML**

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="invalid_day">
      <div class="day">29</div>
    <td class="invalid_day">
      <div class="day">30</div>
    <td class="invalid_day">
      <div class="day">31</div>
    <td>
      <div class="day">1</div>
    <td>
      <div class="day">2</div>
    <td>
      <div class="day">3</div>
    <td>
      <div class="day">4</div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  #removed <td> 5 - 31 for brevity
    <td class="invalid_day">
      <div class="day">1</div>
  </tr>
```

After searching the forum I have tried quite few approaches and all get the td's with div class='day'.
None however have been successful in filtering out those td's with a td class='invalid_day'

**Code tried:**

```
.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[./div[@class="day"]]')
```

Returns:
29,30,31,1,2,3,...31,1

**Code tried:**

```
.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[./div[@class="day"] and not[@class="invalid_day"]]')
```

Returns:
empty

**Also tried the css_selector method with:**

```
.find_elements_by_css_selector('.day:not(.invalid_day)')
```

Returns:
29,30,31,1,2,3,...31,1

**Results I am looking for:**
**1,2,3,...31**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td:not(.invalid_day)>div.day")
```

Comment: Huge thanks, this works!!  Original attempt was by css_selector before trying Xpath.

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath-1.0 expression should do the job:

```
.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="day" and not(../@class="invalid_day")]')
```

Output is:

> 1,2,3

To get the `<td>` elements, you can simply append a `/..` to the XPath or use the following expression:

```
.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[./div/@class="day" and not(@class="invalid_day")]')
```

Answer (score 0):

To find all the `<div>` tags with *class* as `day` excluding those with a parent `<td>` with *class*`invalid_day` i.e. **1,2,3,...31**, you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *xpath* 1: Ignoring elements with parent class `invalid_day`

  ```
  //td[not(@class='invalid_day')]//div[@class='day']
  ```

Snapshot:

[image: ignoring_invalid_day_class]

- *xpath* 2: Ignoring elements with any parent class

  ```
  //td[not(@class)]//div[@class='day']
  ```

Snapshot:

[image: ignoring_class]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to find elements that do not include a certain class name with selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54267038/how-to-find-elements-that-do-not-include-a-certain-class-name-with-selenium-and/54268170#54268170)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with bs4.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

divs = soup.findAll("div", class_ = "day")
```

And then to get only the text you can do a .text for every item in the list.