# Click don't working for enabled element in Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I want that some element on page has been clicked. But Selenium click doesn't working. This part of my code:

```
username_form = driver.find_element_by_id('form3-username')
    password_form = driver.find_element_by_id('form3-password')
    username_form.send_keys('SomeLogin')
    password_form.send_keys('SomePass')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='one-factor']/button").click()
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,  "//div/a[@id='notify-toggle' and not(@disabled)]"))
    )
    element.click()
```

and part the page I'm processing:

```
<a id="notify-toggle" class="toggle link">
    <span title="Уведомления" class="data-count" data-count="0" data-icon="">
    </span>
</a>
```

Promlem is `element.click()` doesn't working. i got acquainted with some solution of my problem, but that I find didn't work for me. I trying use xpath expression with `not (@disabled)`
and other solutions, but no one was helpful for me. I have no idea whatsoever why `click` is not working and I'll be glad to any hints

Comment: have you tried going to a deeper layer, I mean trying to do `//div/a/span` instead of `//div/a`?

Answer (score 1):

Target the inner *`<span>`* inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.toggle.link#notify-toggle span.data-count:not(disabled)[title][data-icon]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='toggle link' and @id='notify-toggle']//span[@class='data-count' and @title][@data-icon and not(@disabled)]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to find elements that do not include a certain class name with selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54267038/how-to-find-elements-that-do-not-include-a-certain-class-name-with-selenium-and/54268170#54268170)
- [While fetching all links,Ignore logout link from the loop and continue navigation in selenium java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57293901/while-fetching-all-links-ignore-logout-link-from-the-loop-and-continue-navigatio/57294355#57294355)
- [Protractor - Check if a radio-button is checked or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60184694/how-to-verify-if-a-radio-button-is-checked-or-not-using-protractor-selenium-moch/60184892#60184892)

Comment: I tryed both of your solutions but it still not works(

Comment: Perhaps it will be important, if I add `time.sleep(1)`, then everything works even with my old code. I think, this is means, that button still disabled and I don't understand why